# Using lmfit with miniconda

Tags: python, conda, spyder, miniconda, lmfit

I downloaded spyder using the standalone installer and have since been using miniconda to install packages that don't already come pre-installed (e.g. astropy, matplotlib etc). The way I've been doing this is using the following block of code in the anaconda prompt and then changing the default environment in Spyder to the one I've set up

```
conda create -n spyder-env -y
conda activate spyder-env
conda install spyder-kernels MODULE -y
```

However, when I tried to install **lmfit** in a similar fashion, the prompt said the lmfit package was not available. I then tried using `conda install -c conda-forge lmfit`, which seemed to work, but when I tried to change the environment and subsequently restart the kernel, there was an issue matching the kernel to the environment. I was wondering if there was a standard way of installing **lmfit** using miniconda that allows the package to be imported?

Thanks

Comment: Specifically, the error found when trying to use conda-forge is:

Error while finding module specificaction for 'spyder_kernels.console' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spyder-kernels')

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to install lmfit is `pip install lmfit`.
I have no idea what is going on with the conda environment running your spyder kernel might be.